# Identify sets including tan building and gray engines

Tags: set-identification

These are the last two potentially identifiable LEGO parts received in my garage sale lot find back in 2019 that I am finally getting around to looking at.

[image: I'm thinking a Star Wars collection set related to the Razor Crest but not sure]
[image: I'm pretty sure it's part of Simpson's House but would like confirmation]

Answer (score 4):

The parts on the left picture are from

[75178: Jakku Quadjumper](https://brickset.com/sets/75178-1/Jakku-Quadjumper)

Right picture shows part of

[71006: The Simpsons House](https://brickset.com/sets/71006-1/The-Simpsons-House)